# Sum case with two conditions

Tags: oracle, case

Is it possible to have two conditions with one case statement?

I need help with this statement below and cannot find anything that will help me get my desired result. I'm trying to get the `case` to have `VERIFICATION_TYPE`
to include `NULL` and `Data entry 2`.

```
SELECT 'Data entry 2 not completed' label, 
sum(case when VERIFICATION_TYPE = 'Data entry 2' then 1 else 0 end,  
case when VERIFICATION_TYPE is null then 1 else 0) Value
from CR_MDT c
 full join
    (select v.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by v.FK_CR_MDT_ID order by v.CREATED desc) as rn
        from CR_MDT_VERIFY v) d 
  ON (c.CR_MDT_ID = d.FK_CR_MDT_ID AND d.rn = 1),
  PT_STUDY a,
  PATIENT b
where b.SOCRD_ID=a.FK_SOCRD_ID
and b.SOCRD_ID=c.FK_SOCRD_ID
and PT_STUDY=3
and C.CR_MDT_DT between TO_DATE('01/01/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') and TO_DATE
('12/31/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: Use `OR`.  Like this: 
`case when VERIFICATION_TYPE = 'Data entry 2' OR VERIFICATION_TYPE is null then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: Okay cool. I think I tried that earlier but guess I forgot about it after my computer restarted. Thanks PM77-1!